# knitr: setting 'out.height' does suddenly not keep aspect ratio

Tags: graphics, r-markdown, knitr, aspect-ratio, ioslides

by using `knitr::include_graphics` with option `out.height='50px'` in a rmarkdown ioslides presentation the aspect ratio is not kept on my machine. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Interestingly, this morning it worked. But not after I installed the 
R packages `ggsn, ggmap, plotKML`. Later I removed them, but the problem remains.

I use: Ubuntu 16.04.4, R version 3.4.4, current rmarkdown

Minimal example is:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "May 24, 2018"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo =T)
```

## R Markdown
setting out.height does NOT keep aspect ratio
```{r, out.height='50px', dpi=200}
   knitr::include_graphics("rect_circ.png")
```

setting out.width keeps aspect ratio
```{r, out.width='50px', dpi=200}
knitr::include_graphics("rect_circ.png")
```
````

[image: output looks like this]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you installed the **png** package by chance (it may be a dependency of the packages you mentioned). When **png** is available, `include_graphics()` will try to set the chunk option `out.width` to match your `dpi` setting. In your case, you set the `out.height` option, which leads to the problem of a distorted aspect ratio (the automatically calculated width is 96, and your manual height is 50).

If you have a desired figure size in the output, you may call

```
knitr::include_graphics("rect_circ.png", dpi = NA)
```

to avoid the automatic adjustment of `out.width`. If you have a desired DPI, you should leave out `out.height`, e.g.,

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("rect_circ.png", dpi = 200)
``
````

Answer (score 1):

Within in my `ioslides_presentation` I created a row of jpg-graphics. For this to look nice I needed to set the `out.height` option, so that the pictures build a rectangular block. Usually this worked:

````
```{r, out.height="200px",dpi=200}
maps=c("map_1.jpg","map_2.jpg","map_3.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics(maps)
```
````

But with the **png** package installed the aspect ratio of the pictures was not kept. Applying the above mentioned changes, the chunk which workes looks like this:

````
```{r, out.height="200px"}
maps=c("map_anthroms_full.jpg","map_anthroms_rangelands.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics(maps, dpi=NA)
```
````

**Note:** Setting a resolution within `include_graphics()`  or ```` ```{r, ...} ```` produces the same error.